# (Visual C#) How to detect right mouse?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, mouse

I have run into a problem when trying to detect a right-mouse click. I have a for loop set up `for (;;)` and inside of there need to find out if the right-mouse button is being held down. Is there some kind of function I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Research; experiment; debug; ship!  [ask] --

Comment: Just add a Form_MouseDown event and a Timer_Tick event, then using a TimeSpan check how long the user has held the Right Mouse button down for... easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing I could find was the mousedown and buttonsclick event.

You can find those pages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173998/detect-whether-button-was-right-or-left-clicked) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'd be interested to find a better answer, until then I hope that this is helpful. Good luck.