# swap mouse xbutton1 and xbutton2

Tags: c#, mouse, swap, mouseclick-event

bought a mouse from china and when i tried i realized thumb buttons are swapped
was wondering with C# is it possible to switch these buttons

i was trying something like:

```
    switch(MouseButtons)
    {
    case MouseButtons.XButton1:
    MouseButtons.XButton2;
    break;

    case MouseButtons.XButton2:
    MouseButtons.XButton1;
    break;
    }
```

or maybe something with:

```
    MouseButtonState.Mouse.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Pressed
```

and BTW im a 6monhts newbie with c#

maybe use window hooks? i read about it but i dont know how to apply it.

Comment: Think you can find some inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209217/detect-both-left-and-right-mouse-click-at-the-same-time

Comment: And here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c

Comment: Do you want system-wide switching, or just within your application?

Comment: i already made a tray app which i wanted to activate that option from a menu

Comment: i mean system-wide :)

Comment: you can use [Raxer](https://github.com/BracoZS/Raxer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done via Win API calls, like the keyboard hooks do, you can find samples anywhere.

But that method would be a little overcomplicated, it is much easier to download the program called AutoHotkey from here: http://ahkscript.org/
And use the script provided here by Masonjar13:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/114669-swap-xbutton1-and-xbutton2/

Please note that a character (") is missing. I copy here the fixed solution for the future generations :D

```
$*XButton1::
SendInput {XButton2 down}
while(GetKeyState("XButton1","P"))
    sleep 10
SendInput {XButton2 up}
return

$*XButton2::
SendInput {XButton1 down}
while(GetKeyState("XButton2","P"))
    sleep 10
SendInput {XButton1 up}
return
```

Answer (score -1):

You can switch mouse buttons globally in Windows via Control Panel's applet `Mouse`.

Press `Win+R` -> type `Control` and press `Enter` -> locate `Mouse` -> check `switch buttons`

Comment: i am talking about side buttons on mouse forward/backward and not main left/right button